# SAPUI5 - bind data into SimpleForm

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I'm trying to bind data inside a Simple form after a Omodel.read, this is my code:

```js
oModel.read("/" + sObjectPath + "/to_AL", {
    success: function(oData2, oResponse2) {
        var oModelJson = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData2.results[0]);                             
        that.getView().byId("SimpleFormAnalisi").setModel(oModelJson);
    }
}
```

`oData2.results[0]` contains the data I want to bind, SimpleFormAnalisi is the name of my SimpleForm

```xml
<form:SimpleForm id="SimpleFormAnalisi" 
    editable="false" 
    layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" 
    labelSpanXL="4" 
    labelSpanL="4"
    labelSpanM="12" 
    labelSpanS="12" 
    adjustLabelSpan="false" 
    emptySpanXL="0" 
    emptySpanL="0" 
    emptySpanM="0" 
    emptySpanS="0" 
    columnsXL="2"
    columnsL="2" 
    columnsM="2" 
    singleContainerFullSize="false">
    <form:content>
        <Label text="SST"  textDirection="RTL"/>
        <Text text="{sst}" />
```

I expected into {sst} the value, but is empty.

any help?
best regarsd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nearly everything you are doing in your example is correct. What might be the problem is the databinding in your Text element.

Please take a look at the [docs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.28.33/docs/guide/91f0f3cd6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html), to make sure that your binding syntax is right. JSON models require a `/` binding, which you don't have.

Comment: Thank you!  i forgot the /,   i changed in  <Text text="{/sst}"/>

Comment: Great to hear! Best of luck with UI5 :)